# client-sessions nodejs / Express - error: Cannot set property 'mydata' of undefined

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm trying to use the client-sessions middleware in nodejs / Express and I get the following error: `Cannot set property 'mydata' of undefined.`

I've also looked at this post, but could not find additional clues as to why I may be getting the error. [node-js-client-sessions-not-creating-req-session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267182/node-js-client-sessions-not-creating-req-session)

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const clientSessions = require("client-sessions");

var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false });
var router = express.Router();

app.use(clientSessions({
  cookieName: 'mydata', // cookie name dictates the key name added to the request object
  secret: 'longsecretkeyorwhatever', // should be a large unguessable string
  duration: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // how long the session will stay valid in ms
  activeDuration: 1000 * 60 * 5 // if expiresIn < activeDuration, the session will be extended by activeDuration milliseconds
}));

/* Form POST handler */
router.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req, res) {
    if (!req.body) return res.sendStatus(400);

    if(req.body.firstName){
        req.session_state.mydata = req.body.mydata;
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`client-sessions`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/client-sessions) explains:

> cookie name dictates the key name added to the request object

Since you're setting `firstName` as cookie name, the session object is available as `req.firstName`:

```
req.firstName.mydata = req.body.mydata
```

Comment: Sorry about that, It was a copy / paste error from my original code. I'm still getting the error even when the cookieName is correct.

Comment: You changed the cookie name, but you're not using the correct session variable name. It should be `req.mydata`, not `req.session_state`.

Comment: Thank you for helping me sort through this, it now makes sense. My original error is now gone. I need to read the cookie data from another route js file now, but my data is not available, it is undefined. Is there some trick to that?  I've tried app and client sessions again on the second script, but this does not work.

Comment: You should declare the `client-sessions` middleware only once, on your main app, and before you declare any routers.

Comment: I've attempted to make client-sessions global. I'm now getting: cannot set client-session to non-object. Here is a link to view code of app.js and index.js https://codeshare.io/T76CD

Comment: @M3NTA7 global variables have very limited use in Node/Express. Try this: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/fb3c369aa4f7cde9a63387b1f135e584

Comment: This solved my problem. I guess the key here is to 'app.use' my client sessions in the main script. Then it remains available.